# Karaf 2.3 Camel 2.10 : Is it possible to switch to Spring 3.1?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf

Is it possible to use Spring 3.1 on Karaf 2.3 without worrying about breaking anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a Spring31 feature available with Karaf 2.3.0. 
It might see sub-optimal to provide it as a optional feature but right now the std. features regarding spring for the 2.3.0 line is the spring 3.0.x feature. 
For Out-Of-The-Box support you'll need to wait a bit for Karaf 3.0

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled a bit with this very issue. Basically we are using Camel 2.10.1, Spring Integration 2.1.3.RELEASE (yes I know two integration frameworks), and we were using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, activemq 5.7.0 and Karaf 2.3.0. As Claus says with OSGi it is always a worry and especially when you do not have control over

1. third party OSGi manifests
2. Karaf feature descriptors (this is slightly less of a worry as you can get around this by creating custom distributions).

We also use Spring DM so you have basically three flavours of Spring available 3.0, 3.1 and 2.5.6. You can end up with three versions of spring-core installed for example through transitive dependency resolution or otherwise and depending on startup ordering etc., you can run in to nasty 'uses" constraints which are always a pain and sometimes not so easy to solve.

What we ended up doing is aligning with Karaf and jettisoning Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE in favour of 3.0.7, this was easy in our case as 3.0.7 was fine.

In general I have found that aligning with what the container offers out of the box to be a reasonable strategy in dealing with dependencies.

Comment: please consider to format your answer a bit - one big bunch of unstructured lines is hard to read ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With OSGi there is always a worry :(

Camel supports both Spring 3.0 and 3.1. So from Camel point of view you should be okay. Karaf comes out of the box with Spring 3.0.7, and you would need to re-configure Karaf to use Spring 3.1.x instead.

IMHO this is wrong (eg Karaf exposing Spring 3.0.7 out of the box), as I believe Karaf should not force users into a specific Spring version. But let end users freely choose what Spring they want to use. And even have Spring 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2 run side by side, as needed by your applications deployed in the container. Or at least Karaf should IMHO make it much easier to choose which Spring versions to expose/use out of the box.

There is discussion on the Karaf @dev mailing list about this issue, and how to address this.
http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Apache-Karaf-2-3-0-very-close-tp4026295.html
and here
http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Re-3rd-Party-Feature-Definitions-tp4026366.html

Raise your voice on these mailing lists as the Karaf team is listing there!